# Outlook delegates users lose their Editor Permissions to shared calendars periodically

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

Having an annoying re-occurring problem in our company with on premise Exchange 2016 where people who have been assigned Editor permissions to other people's calendars periodically will lose their permissions, or they will manifest themselves in a way that Outlook won't open for the user. This is particularly prevalent when the user works in Online mode or has their own mailbox cached but has "Download shared folders" unchecked. Sometimes it just manifests itself as the user cannot create a calendar entry in their managers calendar (they can still see details) they will get the message "You do not have permission.."  Other times they won't be able to open Outlook at all and they will get the message "Cannot expand folder. The set of folders cannot be opened. The attempt to log on to Microsoft Exchange has failed."

All of these are generic messages I know.  I have recreated profiles hundreds of times, wiped machines, re-installed Office, able to re-create issue with same user over multiple test machines.  I have migrated mailboxes to new databases.  It seems I can sometimes get it working by restarting the `Restart-WebAppPool MSExchangeAutodiscoverAppPool` and keep rebooting the users PC, trying to login, removing the profile, rebooting, try again. 99% of time it will start working and they will get access back to the calendars. Not always though, for example though I currently have a user with a Desktop and Laptop. The Desktop is working fine, the Laptop she can open Outlook but no matter what I do I cannot go her into peoples calendars with Editor permissions. I have removed and re-added all the permissions on Exchange Server, re-added outlook profile many times. Just cannot get it working!

OWA always works though, on all calendars.

I am all out of ideas!  Does anyone have anywhere I can start looking or any ideas?

Thank you.